# Debugging a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, class-library

I have a few class libraries in my ASP.net Web Application. I have been debugging them with no problems then suddenly, BAM! Monday morning I get this error and I can hit any break points:

**The following module was built wither with optimizations enabled or without debug     information:**

**To debug this module, change its project build configuration to Debug mode. To supress this message, disable "warn if no user code on launch" debugger option.**

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this?

thanks!

Comment: You did check you're actually in Debug mode, just like the helpful text says, right?

Comment: Yes, in  debug mode, selected it from the drop down and also in the config manager

Comment: Then you should check that the class-libraries you are referencing has been built with debug-configuration as well.

Comment: Do you have any more information regarding debug-configuration settings for a class library? It used to work!

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbars at the top of Visual Studio, theres a drop-down indicating whether to build the current solution with debug- or release-configuration. This drop-down menu usually resides next to the "play"-button you'd press to `Start debugging`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx