# Debugging a class in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, class

I have an asp.net web app, and I have added some related class projects to my solution file. When I run the web app, I want to break and step through the code in the class (when a class is referenced).

I don't get an error messages. The code in the class project just does not kick in.

I have searched and read this post [Debugging a Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8789320/247562) but no luck.

How do I get that to work?

Comment: Have you tried breaking just before the class gets invoked, and then hitting *step into*?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have `<compilation debug="true"/>` set in your web.config file? Are the classes in the same assembly as the rest of the application?

edit: The only other thing I can suggest is stop IIS and/or all instances of the vs development server, clean the project, rebuild, and give it another shot. Also be sure there is only one web.config and you aren't running in release against Web.Release.config or something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to stop the ASP.NET process? I usually have this problem when the asp.net service is still running, and I compile (by asp.net service I mean the icon that appears near computer clock). Try to close that, recompile, then run.

Comment: I have stopped the service; I have shut down and re-launched vs2010, I have rebooted the machine as well.... no luck

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens. Check Debug>Modules to see if there is your dll loaded. It seems that VS debugger doesn't have .pdb file available. Clear Temporary ASP.NET Files in your .NET folder, Clean/Rebuild and try debug again.

Also do not forget to run VS as Administrator. Try to Attach to process instead of F5.

Comment: How can I "attach to process"? I mean I know where to find that in the menu item.. but how do I know which process to select?  By the way... I am using IIS

Comment: In "Attach to process" there is column ID, which contains ProcessID. Run TaskManager and in Command column you can see name of your AppPool and its ProcessID.

Answer (score 0):

You can call in your code this function, and the debugger will pop-up

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`

alternative you can call the `Debug.Fail("Stop me to see what next");`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "call your code in this function". Can you explain please?

Comment: @LearningCSharp at the line you wish to break and start the debugger, place this code. When your function run and reach this line the debugger will pop up.

Comment: @LearningCSharp If your program reach this line and the debugger is not popup, then ether you have compile it with out debug=on, ether you need to restart the iis, with the iis-admin.